# Matching names and assigning unique identifier - master client index

Tags: sql-server

```
create table dbo.data1
(
    ClinetKey int, 
    SourceID int, 
    SourceName varchar(5),
    ClientID int,
    ClientFirstName varchar(50),
    ClientLastName varchar(50),
    UID int
);

insert into dbo.data1 (ClinetKey, SourceID, SourceName, ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, UID)
values (1, 100101, 'db1', 1001, 'Tomas', 'Jones');
insert into dbo.data1 (ClinetKey, SourceID, SourceName, ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, UID)
values (1, 100308, 'db2', 1003, 'Toma', 'Jones');
insert into dbo.data1 (ClinetKey, SourceID, SourceName, ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, UID)
values (1, 100909, 'db3', 1009, 'Thhoma', 'Jones');
insert into dbo.data1 (ClinetKey, SourceID, SourceName, ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, UID)
values (1, 111001, 'db4', 11155, 'Tomass', 'Jones');
insert into dbo.data1 (ClinetKey, SourceID, SourceName, ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, UID)
values (1, 122033, 'db5', 1233, 'Toma', 'Jones');
insert into dbo.data1 (ClinetKey, SourceID, SourceName, ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName, UID)
values (1, 133009, 'db1', 1009, 'Tomas', 'Jones');
```

Based on the matching name logic I need to assign a unique identifier or unique value. Like in the data above all the names sound similar and very close if I need to assign a unique value to the it will be the same for all the 6 records.

Initially the UID is null or do not have a value when loaded into the table, but the next day when a new record comes in then it should check the records and if the record is already present then the assign the existing UID to it and if it is all together a new record then assign a new UID

Could anyone suggest on how to go about it.

Comment: Please rectify the query. There are several syntax error

Comment: updated the insert query, it should work now

Comment: `Should` ? Did you try at all ?

Comment: Typo? Is it really the `ClinetKey` - shouldn't this be `ClientKey` ?!?!?

Comment: yes, spelling mistake, how does it matter. If you could me of suggest me on how to go about it or help me with a solution that would be wonderful